# Find source of token handle leak in managed process

Tags: c#, wcf, memory-leaks, windbg, handle

I'm investigating a handle leak in a WCF service, running on .NET 4.6.2. The service runs fine but over time handle count keeps increasing, with thousands of `Token` type handles sitting around in the process. It seems memory is also leaking very slowly (likely related to the handle leak).

Edit: it looks like event and thread handles are also leaked.

Process Explorer shows that the suspect handles all have the same name:

```
DOMAIN\some.username$:183db90
```

and all share the same address.

I attached WinDbg to the process and ran `!htrace -enable` and then `!htrace -diff` some time later. This gave me a list of almost 2000 newly opened handles and native stack traces, like this one:

```
Handle = 0x000000000000b02c - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x000000000000484c, Process ID = 0x0000000000002cdc

0x00007ffc66e80b3a: ntdll!NtCreateEvent+0x000000000000000a
0x00007ffc64272ce8: KERNELBASE!CreateEventW+0x0000000000000084
0x00007ffc5b392e0a: clr!CLREventBase::CreateManualEvent+0x000000000000003a
0x00007ffc5b3935c7: clr!Thread::AllocHandles+0x000000000000007b
0x00007ffc5b3943c7: clr!Thread::CreateNewOSThread+0x000000000000007f
0x00007ffc5b394308: clr!Thread::CreateNewThread+0x0000000000000090
0x00007ffc5b394afb: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateUnimpersonatedThread+0x00000000000000cb
0x00007ffc5b394baf: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::MaybeAddWorkingWorker+0x000000000000010c
0x00007ffc5b1d8c74: clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x0000000000000024
0x00007ffc5b1d8d27: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x000000000000003f
0x00007ffc5b1d8cae: clr!ThreadPoolNative::RequestWorkerThread+0x000000000000002f
0x00007ffc5a019028: mscorlib_ni+0x0000000000549028
0x00007ffc59f5f48f: mscorlib_ni+0x000000000048f48f
0x00007ffc59f5f3b9: mscorlib_ni+0x000000000048f3b9
```

Another stack trace (a large portion of the ~2000 new handles have this):

```
Handle = 0x000000000000a0c8 - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x0000000000003614, Process ID = 0x0000000000002cdc

0x00007ffc66e817aa: ntdll!NtOpenProcessToken+0x000000000000000a
0x00007ffc64272eba: KERNELBASE!OpenProcessToken+0x000000000000000a
0x00007ffc5a01aa9b: mscorlib_ni+0x000000000054aa9b
0x00007ffc5a002ebd: mscorlib_ni+0x0000000000532ebd
0x00007ffc5a002e68: mscorlib_ni+0x0000000000532e68
0x00007ffc5a002d40: mscorlib_ni+0x0000000000532d40
0x00007ffc5a0027c7: mscorlib_ni+0x00000000005327c7
0x00007ffbfbfb3d6a: +0x00007ffbfbfb3d6a
```

When I run the `!handle 0 0` command in WinDbg, I get the following result:

```
21046 Handles
Type            Count
None            4
Event           2635 **
Section         360
File            408
Directory       4
Mutant          9
Semaphore       121
Key             77
Token           16803 **
Thread          554 **
IoCompletion    8
Timer           3
TpWorkerFactory 2
ALPC Port       7
WaitCompletionPacket    51
```

The ones marked with `**` are increasing over time, although at a different rate.

Edit 3:
I ran `!dumpheap` to see the number of `Thread` objects (unrelated classes removed):

```
!DumpHeap -stat -type System.Threading.Thread
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007ffc5a152bb0      745        71520 System.Threading.Thread
```

Active thread count fluctuates between 56 and 62 in Process Explorer as the process is handling some background tasks periodically.

Some of the stack traces are different but they're all native traces so I don't know what managed code triggered the handle creation. Is it possible to get the managed function call that's running on the newly created thread when `Thread::CreateNewThread` is called? I don't know what WinDbg command I'd use for this.

Note: 
I cannot attach sample code to the question because the WCF service loads hundreds of DLL-s, most of which are built from many source files - I have some very vague suspicions in what major area this may come from but I don't know any details to show an MCVE.

Edit: after Harry Johnston's comments below, I noticed that thread handle count is also increasing - I overlooked this earlier because of the high number of token handles.

Comment: OK, that one looks more relevant.  I wouldn't worry about the event handles for the time being, that might not even be a leak.  That many token handles, on the other hand, is definitely odd.  Sadly, I'm not familiar with CLR debugging so can't be much help, apart from suggesting that you look for code using classes from the System.Security.Principal namespace.  You might be leaking a WindowsIdentity object perhaps?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good idea - I'll check for those. After your comment, I started checking event handles, too, and I'm fairly sure they're also leaking.

Comment: The event handle creation shown in the stack trace looks legitimate to me, probably an internal event object used by CLR to manage worker threads.  But of course that doesn't preclude there being other event objects or duplicate handles that are leaking.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I believe you're right. I think those event handles are leaking somehow - they're all unnamed event handles and their count seems to be increasing slowly. Since I updated the question, 400+ event handles were created.

Comment: You're not leaking *threads* by any chance? :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm not sure yet - after my last comment, I noticed that the thread handle count is also increasing, but at a much lower rate. It's funny that you just asked that now. Is there a reason for that question? The thread count is pretty steady (~60) but the thread handle count is now 600+.

Comment: No particular reason, it was just a thought.  I'm not sure whether it is normal for a CLR program to have lots more thread handles than threads.  I guess you might be leaking System.Threading.Thread objects, for example, that could explain both the thread handles and the event handles.  Perhaps even the token handles, though that seems like more of a long shot.  (The thread count itself only includes live threads, not threads that have exited but are still referenced.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, that was my thought exactly after checking the thread handle count. I'll see how many thread objects are sitting in the heap - if it's much more than the thread count, it's a sign of a leak (and the GC root may even tell me where they come from).

Comment: Do you have any way to search the heap for objects that contain the value of one of the leaked token handles, e.g., `0x000000000000a0c8` for the posted stack trace?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think so but I'll have to read the WinDbg documentation - I don't know all that many commands. In the meantime, I confirmed that threads are being leaked - I have as many `Thread` objects sitting around as thread handles. That was very good advice, thank you.